# iPhone iOS "face in the hole" kind of app, how to stitch two images together?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm building a "face in the hole" or "photo booth" kind of app where the user's face can be inserted into an existing image using face detection technology. I'm getting the "cutout" `UIImage` face boundaries by using face detection.

See the sharp boundary between the face and hair close to the guy's ear below. How can such transition be smoothed and blended together better? I know that there are apps that "expand" pictures, is there some kind of a well known algorithm I can use for this purpose?

[image: face detection example]

My question is how to paste in the user's face into such an image? I was thinking of adding a transparent mask over the cutout's face (effectively cutting out a hole for the face), and substituting the user's face from a live camera feed from a view located behind the cutout.

What concerns me is that this method would create sharp edges around the edge of the cut out face. How can I smooth this edge? Should my transparent mask rather than being pure alpha channel instead be an gradient with alpha channel of 1 in the middle and less on the outer edges?

**How can I blend two images and make the boundary between them disappear or be a lot less noticeable?**

Comment: you should start with reading https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use two UIImageview loaded with two PNG files, you can save the PNG with image editing apps like Photoshop preserving transparencies. 
So you could avoid masks, just use a PNG with a gradient that ends in transparency where needed.

Remember that when you'll add the UIImageview with:

```
UIImageView* myPortrait = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPortrait" ofType:@"png"]]];
myPortrait.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 80, 100);
[self.view addSubview:myPortrait];
UIImageView* photoWithHole = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photoWithHole" ofType:@"png"]]];
photoWithHole.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:photoWithHole];
```

You should remember that the images are displayed on a first-in, last-out basis so remember to add the portrait before the photo with the hole.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the images pre-loaded within the app (user can take any image from the web and create a face in the hole effect), so I cannot do this kind of image manipulation.

Comment: You can manipulate images programmatically, just read this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

Comment: Here's the iOS equivalent link:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101

Answer (score 0):

Check OpenCV libray. Almost any feature like you wish are generally executed with OpenCV.

OpenCV is a c++ image detection and manipulation library.
There is a objC++ wrapper framework xCode.

learn openCV basics for iOS.

Embed OpenCV Framework into your xCode project.

Change m extension of your viewController to mm

Change h extension of your viewController to hpp

import opencv2/opencv.hpp
...
...
...
...

**Things you should probably check :**
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0

http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_Image_Object_Detection_Face_Detection_Haar_Cascade_Classifiers.php

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gdy3fLS_fZA

Or you may use CoreImage

https://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5